# TabNavigator inside StackNavigator - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I am trying to place a TabNavogator inside a StackNavigator and it is complaining that it has to be a react component.

I have attached the code and the error screen shot.

Once I pass login screen I want tabs, so in Login.js on click of a button I am moving to Tabs but I think the problem is in router.js where I might have been doing it wrong.

It would be very helpful if you could suggest how to correct it

Thanks
R

router.js

```
 import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from '../../scripts/components/pages/Login';
import WalkThrough from '../../scripts/components/pages/WalkThrough';
import Transactions from '../../scripts/components/pages/Transactions';
import UserProfile from '../../scripts/components/pages/UserProfile';


export const Root = StackNavigator({          
    WalkThrough: {
      screen: WalkThrough,
      navigationOptions:{
        title: 'WalkThrough',
      },
    },    
    Login:{
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Login',
      },
    },
    Tabs: {
      screen: Tabs,
    }, 
  }, {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'screen',
  });

  export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Transactions: {
      screen: Transactions,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Transactions',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
      },
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: UserProfile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
      },
    },
  });
```

index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Root} from './config/router';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return <Root/>;
    }
}

export default App;
```

Main index.js (FYI)

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import app from './app/index';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('DoPayRetail', () => app);
```

And from Login screen I want to move to Tabs.

Login.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

class Login extends Component{

    goToNext = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Tabs');
    };

    render(){
      const {navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      return (
        <View style = {styles.container}> 
          <Text> Login screen
          </Text>
          <Button
            onPress={this.goToNext}
            title="Go to next page"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });

  export default Login;
```

This is my error message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In router.js, place the declaration and initialization of the `Tabs` variable above `Root`'s initialization. You are currently using variable before declaring it. I think that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the StackNavigator in the same page as a React component (your Tabs TabsNavigator) this error will show up. Try moving out Tabs to it's own file.

Comment: Hello @ehacinom I tried that but it still has the same issue.

Comment: hm. do you need a `navigationOptions: {title: 'Tabs'}` in the stacknavigator to tell `this.props.navigation.navigate('Tabs');` where to go?

Comment: added that too but still it says 'The component for route 'Tabs' must be a React component'. any thing else you suggest

Comment: if you're sure the path is right, have you tried a different simple basic component there instead of Tabs? I would try that to make sure it's a tab specific problem. Also, what version of react-navigation do you have? A bunch of minor breaking changes happened in react-navigation 2. I'll try putting a tabnavigator in a stacknavigator tomorrow too

Comment: Just an FYI, StackNavigator and TabNavigator can be on the same page.